# IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, jwt

I have the following code and when I call the api endpoint I get error `Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.`

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
{
    cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false
    };
});
```

Why is this happening if I am setting the `ValidateIssuerSigningKey=false` ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Please refer to thread : https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1741

> you can set the delegate TokenValidationParameters.SignatureValidator to just return a JwtSecurityToken.

Currently you can't only set `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` to false to skip the signature validation .As a workaround , you can set the delegate TokenValidationParameters.SignatureValidator to just return a JwtSecurityToken :

```
ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
SignatureValidator = delegate (string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters)
{
    var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);

    return jwt;
},
```

Comment: Any idea why setting only the "ValidateIssuerSigningKey" doesn't do the job? Thanks as well for the workaround. Worked for me.

Comment: @Tony Could it be that your `false` turns off checking something else than what you think? There's `SingatureValidator` but also `IssuerSigningKeyValidator`. If we turn off the check by `ValidateIssuerSigningKey`, then perhaps the latter (i.e. ISK-validator) doesn't take effect. However, the fomrer (i.e. S-validator) still kicks in? And if **that one** requires the authority to be specified or something, you get a failure. What do you think?

Comment: In case you are on .NET 5/6/7/8 and higher take in count you need to use Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken instead of JwtSecurityToken. So the line should be like ---->   var jwt = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken(token);

Comment: very good. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only check this if you are sure your jwks config is correct.

Be aware, this can also happen if you have References to Both `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` & `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`

Remove all references to System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, clean your solution (manually remove bin/obj folders)

Retry.

We had this issue after an upgrade from .NET 6 to .NET 8